# Is there a more generalized 2nd order ODE that admits parametric solutions of the form $\Psi(x,y')=C_1$, $\Phi(y,y')=C_2$ than $y''=f(y')$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE
\begin{align}\tag{1}
y''=f(y').
\end{align}
In the case that an inverse function to $\smallint \mathrm d\xi/f(\xi)$ cannot be found we can find a neat parametric solution to (1). Separately, multiply by $1/f(y')$ and $y'/f(y')$ then integrate to yield the two equations
\begin{align}\tag{2}
x=\int\frac{\mathrm dy'}{f(y')} +C_1\quad \text{and}\quad y=\int \frac{y'\mathrm dy'}{f(y')}+C_2,
\end{align}
where $y'$ can now be considered our parameter. I am trying to find other cases where such parametric solutions exist.

> Is there a more generalized 2nd order ODE that admits a parametric solution of the form
> \begin{align}\tag{3}
> \Psi(x,y')=C_1,\quad \Phi(y,y')=C_2
> \end{align}
> than $y''=f(y')$?

An attempt on my end: Essentially, I want the two equations in (3) to be equivalent once we take a derivative. Doing so gives
\begin{align}
\Psi_{y'}y''+\Psi_x=0,\quad \Phi_{y'}y''+\Phi_yy'=0.
\end{align}
If we look for a function $E(x,y,y')$  such that these two equations are equivalent we have that
\begin{align}
\Psi_{y'}=E\Phi_{y'}\quad\text{and}\quad \Psi_x=E\Phi_yy',\ \ \ \longrightarrow \ \ \ 
\frac{\Psi_{y'}}{\Psi_x}=\frac{\Phi_{y'}}{\Phi_yy'}.
\end{align}
It must be that
\begin{align}
\frac{\Psi_{y'}}{\Psi_x}=g(y')\quad \text{and}\quad \frac{\Phi_{y'}}{\Phi_yy'}=h(y').
\end{align}
These PDEs have the general solutions
\begin{align}
\Psi(x,y')=\psi\left(x+\int g(y')\mathrm dy'\right),\quad \Phi(y,y')=\phi\left(y+\int y'h(y')\mathrm dy'\right),
\end{align}
for arbitrary functions $\psi$, $\phi$. This result is no different from our solution in (2), as it must hold that $g(y')=h(y')$.